# Recommended way to send SQL like string to backend server in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am struggling to find a good way to send user entered SQL like search criteria to the backend server.

I have an angular application with Spring (java) based backend and Oracle DB. Backend server exposes REST service to receive this input.

User can enter following search string in a text area (user gets help to create this search string). My goal is to send following example search criteria to backend server.

```
'Customer Name' == 'John Doe' AND 'Customer ID' == 123 AND 'Department' == ('Engineering' OR 'Sales')
```

One Approach I can think of is converting this SQL like text string into JSON object and send it to server.

In this case, how will a string with operands be converted into a JSON object? Can I convert the above example string into a JSON object like below?

```
{
  "AND": {
    "operation1": "'Customer Name' == 'John Doe'",
    "operation2": "Customer ID' == 123",
    "operation3": {
      "OR":{
        "operation4":"'Department' == 'Engineering'",
        "operation5":"'Department' == 'Sales'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Problem with this object is, it looks too specific to this case and will be difficult for the server to sanitize the input and convert it back into an actual query string.

Also I can not just send this string as is to the backend as there will be XSS or SQL injection issues.

Can some one suggest a way to send this data to backend? if JSON approach is a good approach, is there a better way to convert the above string to a JSON object?

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to have a locked down user account in the DB. Let the user return any sql they like, and then run that sql under the locked down account and let SQL's permissions worry about the security of it.

Comment: @Iconiq  I checked the possibility but it will be difficult to prevent XSS issues though with your options, SQL injection may get alleviated.

Answer (score 1):

Turn the input into a URL query string, as if the form had fields "Customer Name", "Customer ID" and "Department".

You may want to take a look at https://github.com/forward/sql-parser.

Comment: Thats a good idea, the only problem I can think of is the operands have AND and OR options. Also user will be able to group terms together using brackets. These options will be difficult to represent in the query string. Non the less, thats a good idea and I will definitely try some options around this and update my result.

Comment: Maybe you would still want to keep the backend service simple in its API and split some ORs into multiple HTTP requests and then merge their results.

Comment: For the sake of diversity, the people I work with would collectively never accept to develop this exact feature. So there's yet another option. Not to discourage you, of course. I actually like the idea.